# RoR: Hide/Modify generated labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How can I hide or modify the text of the labels that are displayed auto-magically via form_builder.  For example, I only want the words, Your Business Name:, to be displayed, not, Name.

View code:

```
 <%=f.fields_for :orgs do |orgs_f| %>  
    <div>Your Business Name:<br />
    <%= orgs_f.text_field :name%></div>
 <% end %>
```

---

Output:

Your Business Name:

Name

Test Company

---

Generated HTML Source:

```
<div>Your Business Name:<br />
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label"for="user_orgs_attributes_0_name">Name</label>
<div class="controls">
<input class="span3" id="user_orgs_attributes_0_name" name="user[orgs_attributes][0][name]" size="30" type="text" value="Test Company" />
</div></div></div>
```

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have inadvertently asked a two-part question, which I'd advise against. (Your question should ask one specific question.)

I do know how to change the label, it's quite simple:

`<%= orgs_f.text_field :name, :label => "Your Business Name" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%=f.fields_for :orgs do |orgs_f| %>  
  <%= orgs_f.label_tag(:name, "Your Business Name:") %>
  <%= orgs_f.text_field :name%></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: orgs_f.label works, but it still displays Name, in addition to the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= orgs_f.label :name, "Business name" %>
```

Comment: orgs_f.label works, but it still displays Name, in addition to the label.